# Improve performance for Kafka listeners in spring boot application deployed in PCF

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, pcf

I am working on use case that need to process almost 600 messages/sec (subscribe from topic, Transform, save to SQL Server table and produce back to topic) but we are only processing 100 messages/sec per 5 instance. we cannot increase more instances to achieve this. Any suggestions will be helpful ?

**Tech and Infrastructure**:
spring boot application with Kafka listeners( no batch listener) deployed in PCF. source and out topic each with 10 partitions each. Default properties and settings are using. Transformation taking fraction of milli seconds.

Comment: You need to profile the application to see where the bottleneck is; probably the database? Since you have 2 partitions per instance, you could try increasing the concurrency to 2 so each partition will be processed on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, I improve performance adding concurrency (10) to each listener and increasing partitions in the queue with the following configuration

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor messageProcessorExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    exec.setCorePoolSize(poolSize);
    exec.setMaxPoolSize(poolMaxSize);
    exec.setKeepAliveSeconds(keepAlive);
    return exec;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Request> consumerFactory() {
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Request> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    consumerFactory.setKeyDeserializer(new StringDeserializer());
    consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(new JsonDeserializer<>(Request.class));
    return consumerFactory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Request>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor messageProcessorExecutor,
        ConsumerFactory<String, Request> consumerFactory) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Request> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency(10);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(messageProcessorExecutor);
    return factory;
}

private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupID);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}
```